# How should I modify the pointer arithmetic in my function in order to complete this question?

Tags: c

A binary bar code scan is a bit pattern that contains only 1s and 0s. Write a function that finds the edges of light and dark regions of a binary code. Process an input bit pattern in the following manner:

•Assign a 1 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bits (one bit and it’s previous bit) are different

•Assign a 0 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bit (one bit and it’s previous bit) are the same

•Assign 0 to the first output bit since there is no previous bit for the first bit

For example, input and output bit pattern of the program that detects the edges might look like the following:

Input: 00101101

Output:00111011

Write the function edge() with the following prototype to perform edge detection. The arguments of the function edge() contain the length of the input and output arrays with the same size, the input array a1, and output array a2. Use pointer arithmetic –not subscripting-to visit array elements. In other words, eliminate the loop index variables and all use of the [] operator in the functions. void edge(int *a1, int *a2, int n){}

```
//my attempt

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void edge(int *a1, int *a2, int n);

int main() {

    int i;
    int n = 8;
    int arr[] = {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1};
    int arr2[n];
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    edge(arr, arr2, n);
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr2[i]);
    }


}

void edge(int *a1, int *a2, int n) {


    int *p;
    int *q;

    for(p = a1, q = a2; p < n, q < n; p++) {
        if(*p != *p++) {
            *q = 1;
            q++;
        } else if(*p == *p++) {
            *q = 0;
            q++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the task description as text in the question (not as an external link and not as an image). Also, please describe what error or incorrect behaviour your current code has.

Comment: it wont allow me to do so because I am a new user.

Comment: What do you mean? It certainly should  allow you to type in the description as text.

Comment: [you've got some warnings to clean up](https://godbolt.org/z/ors1rb7nc)

Comment: @kaylum fixed. The code does run but the output for arr2 is way off.

Comment: None of the comparisons in `edge` do what you think they'll do. `*p == *p++` is undefined behavior, and in the `for` condition you're using the comma operator where you probably want `&&`. That can be rewritten to use only one pointer (and no array accesses).

Comment: jabongo, What do you think `p < n, q < n` does?  Why compare a pointer to an `int`?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem in your code is about the usage of ++ operator. Just use paranthesis and the long form of increment operator to avoid any mistakes while dealing with pointer arithmetic. Check this code below:

```
void edge(int *a1, int *a2, int n) {

    int *cur = a1+1;
    int *prev = a1;
    int *y = a2;
    int i;
    
    (*y) = 0;
    y = y + 1;
    
    while(prev != a1 + 7){
        
       if((*cur) == (*prev)){
           (*y) = 0;
       }
       else{
           (*y) = 1;
       }
       prev = prev + 1;
       cur = cur + 1;
       y = y + 1;
    }
    
}
```